# Как исправить код микроразметки Article "Необходимо указать значение для поля image"

Tags: schema.org, микроразметка

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="post">
    <img itemprop="image" src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="/images/image.jpg?t=1543317919" alt="alt"></div>
```

Так показывает не правильно!

А так правильно:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="post">
    <img itemprop="image" src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" src="/images/image.jpg?t=1543317919" alt="alt"></div>
```

Мне нужно первый код оставить, но и чтобы было правильно с точки зрения микроразметки. Яндекс показывает оба правильно, Google первую не правильно.
Помогите исправить.
ссылка тут: [Google проверка](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fgdefit.ru)

Answer (score 1):

В документации сказано, что должен быть указан **url**. И скорее всего гугл на это и ссылается.

```
An image of the item. This can be a URL or a fully described ImageObject.
```

Более подробно  https://schema.org/image.

Можете попробовать [ImageObject](https://schema.org/ImageObject), но я сомневаюсь, что гугл примет:

```
<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img itemprop="url" src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
    <meta itemprop="height" content="20" />
    <meta itemprop="width" content="20" />
  </div>
```